# Domain name resolution not working over VPN to Windows 2003 domain, VPN is on a different subnet

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, vpn, subnet

I am able to browse shares and, sometimes, connect my outlook to the exchange server when connected over VPN to my office's LAN. However I am aware my VPN address is in a completely different subnet to that the server is on. (my server is something like 192.168.0.1 whereas my VPN is 5.*)

The problem is exchange and accessing shares can be slow typically at first and exchange often drops out - I think because more needs to be configured on the Windows server 2003 box for domain lookups?

EDIT: I see someone tried to close this question?! Let me rephrase:

**How should one configure the DNS lookupzones to allow quick resolution of my local domain from a different subnet?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually enter a DNS on the VPN connection then move the VPN connection priority to the top so it was queried before my other connected interfaces:

[image: Network Connections > Advaced Settings]

NOTE: For Hamachi follow this too: http://logmeinwiki.com/wiki/Hamachi:Microsoft_Exchange_Server_connection

Answer (score 1):

A VPN connection is probably going through a WAN with higher latencies and lower throughput, so a performance hit is expected when browsing shares.

It does not matter (much) if your VPN client gets an address from a different subnet when connecting. If you are able to browse shares and connect to Exchange, you probably have set up DNS correctly, but you could double-check by trying to resolve some domain-internal DNS RRs at your VPN client as [described in the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc738991%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
nslookup
[...]
> set q=srv
> _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.your-ad-domain.local
```

If it resolves to your domain controller(s), everything is fine. If not, it obviously belongs changed. How to set up a DNS server for a VPN client depends on your VPN implementation. If you could add the details to your question, someone is likely to give you some advice.

If you are using [Windows RAS](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc786038%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (e.g. PPTP VPNs terminated at your Windows Server), you would need to add the DNS server information for your AD as the [first entry in the RRAS DNS Service search order configuration](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160699). The resolution of short names will not work with this configuration, though - it [does not support the assignment of domain search lists](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200211/en-us), so you will have to use FQDNs for name resolution.

Comment: Thanks, the nslookup does not succeed! (I knew something was wrong).. It seemed to just query my Internet DNS.. My VPN connection has a gateway of 5.0.0.1 and does not have any DNS...

Comment: This is likely to be your main problem then. I've posted some additional information on this topic to my answer article - feel free to provide further configuration information.